# R on OSX 10.10.3: Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk'

Tags: r

I am facing problems, when trying to install packages, I get the following error message:

```
> install.packages("png")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/t    cltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I am uncertain what R is complaining about?

Here is the session info output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] C
```

SOLVED! This question was wrongly marked as a duplicate and by wrongly I mean that there was no valid solution available in the so-called duplicate question. The problem arises when updating to OS X 10.10.3 - 'Something' happens rendering the 'tcltk' unavailable. However simply re-installing XQuartz solved the problem!

Comment: SOLVED! This question was wrongly marked as a duplicate and by wrongly I mean that there was no valid solution available in the so-called duplicate question. The problem arises when updating to OS X 10.10.3 - 'Something' happens rendering the 'tcltk' unavailable. However simply re-installing XQuartz solved the problem!

Comment: I have added your answer to the linked question, thanks for your comment!